# What does angle braces initializer "a[] = <%1%>" means in C++? It gives out ouput as 1

Tags: c++, digraphs

Why this is a valid thing?

```
int a[] = <%1%>;
cout<<a<:0:>;
```

Comment: [Digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) - a sad wart on C++ due to the need to support unfortunate programmers who are playing without a full character set.

Comment: Read Digraphs and trigraphs on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs)

Comment: The problem with marking this as a dupe is that it is impossible to search for the other correct post without knowing that these things are called "digraphs".  It would be nice to have this question available so that search engines could find it for people who have no idea that this is a thing with a name.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - ah, thanks, I guess I misunderstood what it says above "(Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege)" to mean that a closed question is effectively invisible to newcomers.